# Hibernate: OneToMany in the same table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following ‘class’ table:

```
integer id
integer class_id
integer student_id
```

The point here is that it's possible to have multiple `student_ids` under the same `class_id`.

Is it possible to map it to an entity that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "class")
class MyClass {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "class_id")
   long classId;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student_id")
   List<Long> studentIds;
}
```

How to make this work?

Comment: There is one suggestion by Antoniossss, I'm looking for a different approach...if exists..

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass{
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="clazz")
  private List<Student> students;
}

class Student{
   @ManyToOne
   private MyClass clazz;
}
```

and eventually `@Column` with propert ID column names.

Comment: Not sure how this answers my case, is `Student` an entity? it looks like a bidirectional association, can it be unidirectional?

Comment: Yes it can (what is wrong with bidirectionals?). If you use @JoinColumn you can specify what column to joint to in foreigh table. *Not sure how this answers my case* not sure why student is NOT entity. So ye, that solves this issue as well.

Comment: I only have single table named 'class', there is no 'student' table.

Comment: Well you will have to have in order to store multiple entries. Or just save coma separated list as String.